# How to import a customized Ribbon to Excel

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, ms-office, vsto, ribbon

I have made a new `Excel 2010 Add-in` project, with VS10.
When I run it, it opens Excel and show my custom tab.

How do I import this new code/file/files, so my Excel have this new Ribbon tab include, if I open Excel the normal way?

Only thing I can find is how to import .UIexported file, but that's not what I have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Simple way:**

1. Publish your project (project properties > Publish tab > click Publish Now) to a local directory.
2. Double-click the .vsto file that your project generated, then follow the instructions to install it. (If you need to move the file you have to move the other files and subfolders with it.)

**Best way (more difficult):** If you need to distribute your add-in to many users then consider creating an installer for it. [This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsto/ff937654.aspx) outlines how to do it using the Visual Studio setup project template. However the setup project will only handle the basic installation and will not cover scenarios like code signing and proper uninstallation of the add-in. (I found it much easier to create the installer using [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page).)